# How to create textboxfor in view using button and on postback i want to get the inputed values on thIs textBox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

in ASP MVC RAZOR

I want to create a button that when clicked it will add a TextBoxFor and on postback i want to get the inputted value from the textboxes created.

Help is much appreciated :)

Comment: People here tend to ignore (and down vote) these kind of questions, because you're supposed to show a little effort from your part before asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question but I'll do my best and paste some pseudo code here to get you started (if I'm not misunderstanding you).

I declared some complex type to use as a demonstration for the view:

```
public class Derp
{
    public string Flerp { get; set; }
    public string Slerp { get; set; }
    public string Blerp { get; set; }

    public Derp ()
    {
    }
}
```

For some reason you seem to need a button to "create" a textbox to submit.  How about just hiding some form field and using scripts to help you show them?  Maybe somehow like this:

```
@model MVCTest.Derp

<div>
@using (@Html.BeginForm("SaveDerp", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{   
    <div>
        <button onclick="$('#Blerp').show()" value="show">show Blerp</button>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Blerp, new { style = "display: none;" })
    </div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Slerp)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Flerp)

    <button type="submit" value="save"></button>
}
</div>
```

And then submit the form to check if the value has been passed:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveDerp(Derp derp)
{
    try
    {
        var inputText = derp.Blerp;

        //TODO: do some db stuff

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //TODO: stuff...
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Like I said, your question is quite broad and maybe some scripting solution does not work for you but maybe if you want to revise your question then I would recommend sending some code along with it to help us give you answer examples. (help us help you)